# Function as parameter: Unary Operator in swift3

Tags: xcode, swift3, swift-playground

I have been testing out the code in Xcode playground as demonstrated at Apple WWDC 2016.

The code is been copied exact thing as in the presentation but it show errors that my function parameter is "unary operator".

am I missing something?

[See error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l4ZmN.jpg)

[Playground error on function as param](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQJzf.jpg)

and here is the code

```
func filterInst(_ numbers: [Int], _ includeNumber: (Int) -> Bool) -> [Int] {
 var result : [Int] = []
 for number in numbers {
    if includeNumber(number) {
        result.append(number)
    }
 }
 return result
}

let numbers = [4, 17, 34, 41, 82]
func divisibleByTwo(_ number: Int) -> Bool {
    return number % 2 == 0
}

let evenNumbers = filterInst(numbers, divisibleByTwo)
print(evenNumbers)
```

Comment: That code compiles and runs without problems in my Xcode.

Comment: it seems fine to me, but getting error..no idea why..look at error screen

Comment: Is there more code before that function? Did you try to compile it in a new project?

Comment: Remove the previous codes and this is the error I'm getting: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQJzf.jpg

Comment: You should solve the "invalid character in source file" issue first.

Comment: Found the bug, not sure how I created it, when just hitting the spacebar.. Anyway thank you, Martin :)

Answer (score 0):

After debugging I found the issue, it seems there is an invisible character...

so I removed the space and enter space again..then it works..
Xcode bug?

[Xcode screenshot of the invisible char....bug?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PkCYC.jpg)

Comment: That is more likely your fault. Perhaps you accidentally typed "option-space" or something similar?

Comment: yep that must be it, option + space :)   Doh!  8-)